# Python 3 Value Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting an error in python 3. As i am a beginner , i don't know how to tackle it. please help. The code is following: Initially I was getting the value error but after try and except block, i am always getting "that was not a value". what should i do to run the program?

```
import sys
try:
    T= sys.stdin.readline()
    if 1<=int(T)<=int(10):

        for i in range(int(T)):
            N=sys.stdin.readline()
            if 1<=int(N)<=100000:

                x=sys.stdin.readline().split()
                if len(x)==int(N):

                    if 1<=int(max(x))<=1000000: 
                        x=[int(y) for y in x]
                         x=sorted(x)            
                        print (x[len(x)-1]-x[0])
                    else:print('Either value of card too high ')
                else:print('number of values is greater than number of cards')
            else:print('ERROR: cards allowed between 1-100000')
    sys.exit()
```

except ValueError:
    print ('that was not a value')

Comment: This happens when you hit enter without entering a number.

Comment: I am trying it on codechef. no maual input is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import sys
>>> T= sys.stdin.readline()
22
>>> int(T)
22
```

If you don't give any valid input:

```
>>> T= sys.stdin.readline()

>>> int(T)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: on ideone, the out put is always from the except block, it prints "that was not a value", how can i make it correct? thanks for the help

Comment: How can i make sure that user has not left the space blank? can i achieve it somehow that he must enter a value in between restricted values?